# CSS issue with max-width

Tags: html, css

I have a module in joomla that I am trying to make responsive. I will admit I am a bit out of practice. I used this code to set it up:

```html
<table style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 100%;">
<td style="max-width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<p style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%;"><img src="images/logopara1.png" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%;"> </p>
<p style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%;"><img src="images/welcome.png" alt="" /></p>
<p style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%;"> </p>
<p style="text-align: center; max-width: 100%;"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" />               <img src="images/ig.png" alt="" />               <img src="images/tw.png" alt="" />               <img src="images/yt.png" alt="" /></p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p style="text-align: center;"> </p>
```

Im sure i made a hell of a lot of mistakes, but im trying. Anyway, the result is unchanging when scaled down to the size of an iphoneX it still looks like this:[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1jFY.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: tables are bad for responsive design

Comment: I tried without tables, but couldnt get it to work. Can you explain a better way to do it?

Comment: Can you using the flex boxes ? Or you must using the tables ?

Comment: not suer, id be willing to give them a try

Comment: you created a table to have only one cell ? so some remove, it's useless

Comment: all i want to do is make all those things responsive, in relation to the page and each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are not responsive, if you want to be have table responsive you must put a div with horizontal scrollbar, so this technique is not user friendly.

Use this container:

```
<div class="module">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>

.module {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px; //or your sidebar width
  padding: 15px; //etc
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block // just if you want to be aligned side by side
}
```